# Cannot access children's attributes in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to convert an HTML table to a 2d python list (list of lists).  Three of the "columns" are just the text of the corresponding HTML table cells and work fine.  However, one "column" should just be the id of the link in the corresponding HTML cell, but I'm unable to access that attribute.

The issue arises when I'm trying to get the link's id.  If I print the .contents of that  element, all it says is "Action."  When I try to access the ['id'] index of that  element it gives me an error.  What is wrong?

```
    bs = BeautifulSoup(page)

    table = bs.find("table", id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports")

    def notHeader(css_class):
        return css_class is not "gridviewheader"

    rows = table.find_all("tr", class_=notHeader)

    result = []

    for x in range(0, len(rows)):
        allcols = rows[x].findAll('td')

        tempRow = []
        print(allcols[0].contents[0])  #only prints Action
        tempRow.append(allcols[0].contents[0]['id'])  #TypeError: string indices must be integers
        tempRow.append(allcols[2].string)
        tempRow.append(allcols[3].string)
        tempRow.append(allcols[5].string)
        amended = -1
        for existing in result:
            if tempRow[1] == existing[1] and tempRow[2] == existing[2]:
                amended = 1
        if amended == -1:
            result.append(tempRow)

    print (ids)
```

Comment: If it only prints `Action` then `contents[0]` is a `NavigableString` object; web page text in other words.

Comment: Perhaps the `id` attribute is on the `<td>` tag instead? In that case use `allcols[0].attrs['id']` or `allcols[0]['id']`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It makes sense that it somehow became a string given the errors.  But I can't figure out where it switched from being aBeautifulScope object to a string?

Comment: `NavigableString` **is** a BeautifulSoup object. Just not a Tag. Your HTML content tree consists of more than just tags, after all.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Is there a way to tell what part of the tree is a tag and what part is a string? Also, wrt your second comment, I did check and the relevant id field is on the link, not the <td>

Comment: Without a sample of HTML content, it is very hard to say anything more. You can test for `isinstance(obj, NavigableString)` (provided you imported the class, `from bs4 import NavigableString`).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: It had to do with using the function in find_all() to eliminate the header row.  I replaced the find_all line with

```
rows = table.find_all("tr")[1:]
```

because the header is always the first line, and it works.